# How to Insert A New Between After a Specific Row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Can you please let me know how I can 
1- insert a new row let say 3 exactly after Existing row 2 
2- Copy Strings from  1 to 2 
3- and finally delete 1

The reason that i have to do this is I have some Drop-down, look ups(which I do not know what they call in excel) in row 1 and i can not load the file like this into GIS software so I need to get rid of that, however I still need to keep the Title headers for further referencing.

thanks
**Update**

```
Sub inserter()
'
' inserter Macro
'

'
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("3:3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: Record a macro and see how it happens and then simply amend the macro?

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, can you please check the updated post if I am doing correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um not exactly. If you notice this line

```
.Rows(1).Copy .Rows(2)
```

It follows what you had in point 2 and it not as per what you recorded.

Macro recorder gives all kinds of extra code. The code that you gave can be written as

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Rows(3).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Rows(1).Copy .Rows(2)
        .Rows(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
End Sub
```

You might also want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:

```
Rows("3:3").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hello"
Range("B4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Rows("4:4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

but better learn to save macros. I mean  I dont have in my head this code, everytime I need some code I just save it, btw avoid .select, do something like this instead:

```
Rows("3:3").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Hope it helps